# Opening MIDI Synth before creating JFrame causes JVM to hang

Tags: java, swing, jframe, deadlock, javax.sound.midi

While writing a program to MIDI with a Swing interface, I experienced a hang, such that `kill -9` is required.  It is 100% reproducible by running the following program as `java MidiSwingProblem hang0`

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MidiSwingProblem {
    /**
     * JFrame never appears.  Hangs such that `kill -9` is required.
     */
    public static void hang0() throws MidiUnavailableException {
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MIDI Swing Hang 1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * JFrame never appears.  Hangs such that `kill -9` is required.
     */
    public static void hang1() throws MidiUnavailableException {
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("MIDI Swing Hang 2");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void solution0() throws MidiUnavailableException {
        // It doesn't matter whether .getSynthesizer() or new JFrame() is
        // called first.  It seems to work as long as synth.open() happens
        // after new JFrame().
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MIDI Swing Solution 0?");
        synth.open();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void solution1() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
                    synth.open();
                } catch (MidiUnavailableException noMidi) {
                    noMidi.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MIDI Swing Solution 1?");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void solution2() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
                    synth.open();
                } catch (MidiUnavailableException noMidi) {
                    noMidi.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("MIDI Swing Solution 2?");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException
                                                , IllegalAccessException
                                                , InvocationTargetException {
        MidiSwingProblem.class.getMethod(args[0], new Class[0]).invoke(null);
    }
}
```

I assume that there is a deadlock in `hang0()`, and that it's my fault rather than a bug in J2SE.  (I've verified the behaviour on Java 1.7 and 1.8 on OS X.)

I have three questions:

1. Taking a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16266728/1157100), I also tried writing it as `hang1()`, but that didn't work.  Why is `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` insufficient?
2. If I rearrange the lines (see `solution0()`) to call `synth.open()` *after* `new JFrame()`, then it works!  Why?  Is `solution0()` proper, or am I just getting lucky?  It seems like a flimsy solution to me.
3. For good measure, I've also written `solution1()` and `solution2()`, both of which do not seem to hang.  Are these versions more correct than `solution0()`, or are they overkill?  Having the `synth` object in a separate thread makes it hard for the rest of the program to use it.

Answer (score 4):

In case of thread there is no guarantee that what thread will run first.

So I suggest you to write the code in [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)  to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

Read more

- [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
- [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)

sample code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
            synth.open();
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MIDI Swing Solution 1?");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain `hang1()`? It seems to satisfy the requirement to initialize `JFrame` in the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: `hang1()` is working fine for me but it takes time to show the window.